# Como formatar um arquivo txt, inserindo colunas e alterando formato da data e da hora com script em php

Tags: php, formatação, txt

Tenho arquivo texto gerado apartir de um dispositivo de controle de acesso, quando baixo o arquivo ele vem sem colunas de identificação, o que preciso fazer?
Inserir colunas e aleterar o formato da data, para que o arquivo possa ser importado para o mysql.
Desta forma que eu consigo visualizar: 
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Esta é uma parte do arquivo, uma linha com total de 8 colunas :

```
0000000001 001 00000000000090000001 01/01/2014 00:00:38 1 0 5
```

Comment: Pergunta falta uma melhora no itens relacionados! Cite exemplos, cite eventos reais, onde os dados são obtidos e tudo que puder ajudar a solucionar seu problema!

Comment: Certo Vírgilio!

Comment: Talvez você possa utilizar a função explode do PHP http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php, primeiramente leia o arquivo txt e depois separe o conteúdo a cada espaço em branco. No link postado acima tem alguns exemplos, veja se te ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Esta solução deve lhe ajudar:

```
<?php
$linha  = "0000000001 001 00000000000090000001 01/01/2014 00:00:38 1 0 5";
$partes = explode(" ", $linha);
$i = 0;
foreach ($partes as $campo) {
    echo 'campo' . ++$i . ' = ' .  $campo . "\n"; 
}
```

Resulta em:

```
campo1 = 0000000001
campo2 = 001
campo3 = 00000000000090000001
campo4 = 01/01/2014
campo5 = 00:00:38
campo6 = 1
campo7 = 0
campo8 = 5
```

Na prática, basta você pegar cada elemento do array `$partes` e colocar dentro de cada campo específico que você deseja. 
Ex:

```
mysql_campo1 = $partes[0];
mysql_campo2 = $partes[1];
mysql_campo3 = $partes[2];
.
.
.
```

Veja funcionando em https://ideone.com/WJEeDy

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando como exemplo o arquivo **data.txt** com os seguintes dados:

```
0000000001 001 00000000000090000001 01/01/2014 00:00:38 1 0 5
0000000002 010 00000000000090000001 01/03/2015 00:00:38 1 0 5
0000000003 011 00000000000090000001 11/03/2014 00:00:38 1 0 5
0000000004 100 00000000000090000001 19/04/1999 08:50:38 1 0 5
```

Localizado no mesmo diretório que o **index.php** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php

// Abre arquivo com conteúdo
$arquivo = fopen("data.txt", "r");

// Percorre linha a linha do arquivo obtendo dados
while (!feof($arquivo)) {

    $linha = fgets($arquivo);

    $colunas = explode(" ", $linha);

    $arrayColunas = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($colunas as $coluna) {
        $arrayColunas[++$i] = $coluna;
        if($i==4){
            // Ajusta data
            $arrayColunas[$i] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $arrayColunas[$i])->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($arrayColunas);
}
fclose($arquivo);
```

O código efetua a abertura do arquivo para leitura e através de um loop **while** obtém linha à linha até chegar no final do arquivo (**feof**), para cada linha obtida utilizamos a função explode para dividir seu conteúdo em um array onde as colunas estão sendo identificadas pelo espaço em branco (poderia ser outros caracteres, por exemplo **;** ), a função **foreach** percorre cada coluna obtida adicionando-a à um novo array, quando a coluna for a de data, converte seu formato para inserção em base de dados.

Nesse exemplo estou convertendo o array em um JSON e imprimindo em tela, porém o array pode ser utilizado para efetuar inserções em base de dados ou reescrita em arquivos de acordo com o necessário.